# Safari blocks JQuery if same Ajax request is fired multiple times

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, safari

This might be a stupid question, but I can't get this to work in Safari (8.0). I have a progress bar which should update automatically while uploading a file. It works perfectly in FF and in Chrome but Safari doesn't update my view. If I got it right, then Safari does not deal with synchronous events, which means the browser blocks every following JQuery. In my opinion this does not matter as one task is finished BEFORE the next one is fired.

Can someone please help me with this? I'm very confused...

Thank you!

I have the following:

```
// main Ajax call
function test() {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'getProgressBarPercentage',
        type: 'GET',
        data: 'key=fileUpload',
        async: false,
        success: function(res) {
            console.log(res);   // I do see all values in the console log 
            var percentVal = res + "%";
            $('#pTesting').attr('aria-valuenow', '100').css('width', percentVal); // this only works in Chrome and FF
        },
        error: function(res) {
            console.log('FAIL');
        },
        complete: function(res) { doAgain(); } // if Ajax request is complete ...
    });
}

// ... fire test() again
function doAgain() {
    setTimeout(function(){test();},500);
}

// triggers event after hitting an upload button
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#uploadSubmit").click(function () {
          test();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. It has nothing to do with Safari, but with bad coding. It is important that proper return values are defined in the associated controller actions.

Check [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030472/why-does-the-browser-lock-when-having-2-ajax-calls) for a detailed description.